# Thymeleaf Cannot convert Multipart file to byte

Tags: spring, thymeleaf, multipartform-data

I have a problem about converting multipart file to byte[] as inserting image into the database.

When I use this input type , I can have no error with inserting process.

```
<input type="file" name="file"
                    class="form-control mb-4 col-4" placeholder="Image">
```

But When I use this, there is a typo related with converting process.

```
<input type="file" name="file" th:field="*{image}"
                    class="form-control mb-4 col-4" placeholder="Image">
```

Employee Class related wit image

```
@NotNull(message="is required")
@Column(name="IMAGE")
private byte[] image;

@Transient
private String base64Image;

public byte[] getImage() {
        return image;
}


    public void setImage(byte[] image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

public String getBase64Image() {
        base64Image = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(this.image);
        return base64Image;
}


public void setBase64Image(String base64Image) {
        this.base64Image = base64Image;
}
```

After I know th:field  , multipart file is defined shown below in controller part

```
@RequestParam("image") MultipartFile file <-> th:field="*{image}"
```

How can I fix this coverting process?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public String imageMultipart(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile multipartFile) throws IOException {
        byte[] bytes = multipartFile.getBytes();
        return "something";
    }
```

Comment: @RequestParam("file") cannot be matched the value coming from th:field="*{image}". It throws converting error. Without using th:field="*{image}", there isn't any typo.